# Kechari Mudra and Khechari vidhya going beyond placing the tongue in the nasopharynx (10th gate)

Tags: moksha, yoga-sutras, samadhi, kriyayoga, raja-yoga

The Krishna-Yajur veda, yoga-kundalini upanishad talks about the tongue after entering the nasopharynx and resting comfortably in front of the nasal septum going much further before Khechari mudra being considered complete.

A rough translation of the passed is krishna yajur veda - yoga kundalini upanishad focused only on Khechari mudra. The tongue first enters the bhram-dvar a cavity in the skull after penetrating the 10th door (dasa dvar) then it occupies the cavity fully then penetrates the adamantine door which is impentrable call the bhramgal and eventually breaks into the bhramrand which is a pin sized hole that only the very tip of the tongue can access. The moment its complete the yogi tastes the nectar of the gods and attains samadhi for the first time. This is when Khechari is said to be complete.

Is there any guru living today that has completed this mudra? I have scoured the internet and found 2 or 3 people who claim this but I want to know if you know of someone through word of mouth?

I have practiced and experienced alot of this to be true and am desperately seeking someone who has walked and completed this path before me for advice. This is a request of a humble sadhak to the yoga community. Do any of you know of a guru who has mastered Khechari in its entirety ?

Comment: No true Gurus will tell themselves they have completed infront of many or in public. They will be among us like us but will never expose themselves on internet especially unless its instructed for them to be given to public.!!!!

Comment: Thank you sir. Ask a yoga sadhak I was just searching for someone who can guide me hence I was looking for a guru. Even if a fellow sadhak can mention his guruji if not a the guru himself come claim he knows how to do it then it would be a blessing wouldnt it. Lord Shiva in the Shiva samhita says a sadhak who is practicing khechari vidhya must search the world non stop until he finds a guru with this knowledge. I am humbly seeking the help of people such as yourself for your kindness.

Comment: Guru will come to you... you cannot find! When student is ready teacher will come. So stay pure in mind have devotion. .. your guru will come.